# Cannot connect to softAP hosted on ESP32 IoT device on Windows 10

Tags: wifi, wireless, microsoft-windows

I have an IoT ESP32 device that needs to be configured through its softAP WiFi. When I enter the credentials of that network I get "cannot connect to network". I suspect that it's because softAP does not have a connection to the internet. How I can force my Windows 10 to connect to that network? Or how I can debug what is preventing me from connecting?

Comment: start by checking if the win10 machine has obtained an IP address

Comment: @jsotola no it does not - no packet captured on Wireshark

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that in my case it was because ESP32 had wrong settings for SoftAP.
I debugged it using 3rd machine that captured WiFi packets and it turned out that beacons were sent every 25-30 seconds...